# Dimensions issue in 3D plotting

Tags: scilab

I have wrote the following code in scilab and want to plot it but the plot is not look like 3D. Basically the problem is dimensions, x and y are 1 cross 5 matrices and the function f is 5 cross 5 matrix. I tried to make x and y 5 dimensional by using meshgrid but then the functions can't give me result with that modified values of meshgrid(x,y). The whole code is here.

```
clear; clc;
//Defining the range of Cartesian coordinates (x,y,z)
x = linspace(1,30,5);
y = linspace(0,30,5);
z = linspace(0,30,5);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//This funciton transform Cartesian to Spherical coordinates
function [r, theta, phi]=cart2sph(x, y, z)  
  r = sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2);
  theta = atan(y./x) 
  phi = acos(z./sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2))'
endfunction
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//To get the spherical coordinates from Cartesian uing the above funciton
[r, theta, phi]=cart2sph(x, y, z)  
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Defining spherical hormonic as a funciton of shperical coordinates here.
function [y]=Y(l, m, theta, phi)  
  if m >= 0 then
     y = (-1)^m/(sqrt(2*%pi))*exp(%i*m*phi)*legendre(l, m, cos(theta), "norm")
  else
     y = 1/(sqrt(2*%pi))*exp(%i*m*phi)*legendre(l, -m, cos(theta), "norm")
  end      
endfunction
l = 1; m = -1;
f = Y(l,m,theta,phi); 
//I got the funciton value in spherical coordinates and 
//that spherical coordinates are funciton of Cartesian coordinates. 
//So basically funciton Y is a funciton of Cartesian coordinates (x,y,z). 
//Next to plot funciton Y against (x,y)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
clf(); 
plot3d(x,y,f,flag=[2 4 4]); xtitle("|Y31(x,y)|");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to the range of f which is very small compared to the x and y ones.

To get what you expect you can proceed as follow
    plot3d(x,y,f,flag=[2 4 4]); xtitle("|Y31(x,y)|");
    ax=gca();
    ax.cube_scaling="on";